# The fastest way to write a BufferedImage to disk

Tags: java, performance, file, pdfbox, bufferedimage

I tried a few methods [here](https://github.com/IdiosApps/imageWriteTimer), and basically found that I'm not I/O limited (wrote to SSD and RAMDisk with similar times). I'm aware that there are tools/techniques for JPEG and PNG, such as:

- JPEG - copy an input stream to FileOutputStream [as done by PDFBox's
  ExtractImages](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.java)
- PNG - read/write a line at a time [as done by PNGJ](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pngj/)

Sometimes I will be extracting images from PDFs, so my flow will look like PDFBox's ExtractImages - this writes JPEGs very quickly.
However the more general

```
 ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image, suffix, out);
```

is quite slow for BufferedImages with very large dimensions.

I would actually start with a **PDImage pdImage** object before converting to BufferedImage (very memory usage heavy), if that makes a difference.

Comment: If the images in your PDF are JPEGs, you can speed up things by using the `-directJPEG` option.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I set that as true by default, and it is very fast. As of TwelveMonkey's ImageIO 3.4, its JPEGImageWriter "...can now finally write CMYK JPEG files directly from CMYK BufferedImages". This may improve write  speed for those images (line 400 of ExtractImages).


Now I just need to see if there's a better way to save generic BufferedImages to speed up https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/2d596295ae90ffc34e0c66464040a9f757dd5b0e/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.java#L425.

Comment: After seeing the code I thought about passing a BufferedOutputStream object instead of a FileOutputStream object, but then I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712957/